# Python / Bokeh / Pandas AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'responsive' to Figure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I'm trying to use bokeh and pandas to create a graph.  If ", responsive = True" is not included, the code works.  If it is included, it doesn't work.  Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

```
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show
import pandas

file="adbe.csv"

df=pandas.read_csv(file, parse_dates=["Date"])

p=figure(width=500, height=500, x_axis_type="datetime", responsive = True)

p.line(df["Date"],df["Close"],color="Orange", alpha=0.5)

output_file("Time_Series.html")
show(p)
```

Here's the full error message:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
6 df=pandas.read_csv(file, parse_dates=["Date"])
7
----> 8 p=figure(width=500, height=500, x_axis_type="datetime", responsive = True)
9
10 p.line(df["Date"],df["Close"],color="Orange", alpha=0.5)

```
c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting\figure.py in figure(**kwargs)
   1530 
   1531 def figure(**kwargs):
-> 1532     return Figure(**kwargs)
   1533 figure.__doc__ = Figure.__doc__
   1534 

c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting\figure.py in __init__(self, *arg, **kw)
    163             kw['title'] = Title(text=title)
    164 
--> 165         super().__init__(*arg, **kw)
    166 
    167         self.x_range = get_range(opts.x_range)

c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\bokeh\model.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
    232         kwargs.pop("id", None)
    233 
--> 234         super().__init__(**kwargs)
    235         default_theme.apply_to_model(self)
    236 

c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\has_props.py in __init__(self, **properties)
    245 
    246         for name, value in properties.items():
--> 247             setattr(self, name, value)
    248 
    249     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\has_props.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
    280 
    281             raise AttributeError("unexpected attribute '%s' to %s, %s attributes are %s" %
--> 282                 (name, self.__class__.__name__, text, nice_join(matches)))
    283 
    284     def __str__(self):

AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'responsive' to Figure, possible attributes are above, align, aspect_ratio, aspect_scale, background, background_fill_alpha, background_fill_color, below, border_fill_alpha, border_fill_color, center, css_classes, disabled, extra_x_ranges, extra_y_ranges, frame_height, frame_width, height, height_policy, hidpi, inner_height, inner_width, js_event_callbacks, js_property_callbacks, left, lod_factor, lod_interval, lod_threshold, lod_timeout, margin, match_aspect, max_height, max_width, min_border, min_border_bottom, min_border_left, min_border_right, min_border_top, min_height, min_width, name, outer_height, outer_width, outline_line_alpha, outline_line_cap, outline_line_color, outline_line_dash, outline_line_dash_offset, outline_line_join, outline_line_width, output_backend, plot_height, plot_width, renderers, reset_policy, right, sizing_mode, subscribed_events, tags, title, title_location, toolbar, toolbar_location, toolbar_sticky, visible, width, width_policy, x_range, x_scale, y_range or y_scale
```

Comment: What made you think that `responsive` was a valid argument for `figure` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The `responsive` parameter was removed several years ago. (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/dev-3.0/docs/releases.html)

Deprecations Removed:

The following functions, arguments, or features have were previously deprecated with warnings and instructions for new usage, and have now been permanently removed:

- `--host` argument to bokeh serve
- `responsive` argument to plots and layout functions
- `Plot.toolbar_sticky` property
- `Tool.plot` property
- `bokeh.sampledata.population.load_population` function
- `bokeh.util.notebook` module

In modern versions of Bokeh you can use `sizing_mode` instead, or you can try deleting it from your code. (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html?highlight=sizing_mode#sizing-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Like the error said, Figure has not attribute 'responsive', so, don't use it.

You can check the [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/_modules/bokeh/plotting/figure.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing Ardit Sulce's tutorial? Because I stumbled upoh the same issue. I looked that up and found more explanation on this at https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4620
I managed to get the similar output to `responsive = True` by using `sizing_mode = "scale_width"`

I hope this helps others who stumbled upon the same issue while following the tutorial.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31753644)